# How to fix a "URL Error #:Operation timed out after 300001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received" in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I have the following fatal error when trying to use Curl GET Method  using  woocommerce rest api V3 in WordPress. I have try to set_time_limit(0) and also, try with wp_remote_get method of WordPress but not solve issue. this because I get errors and I'm not able to fix them. I've set the timeout to 30 seconds. Also with this settings I get a timeout error and getting null response from REST API.

Fatal error: cURL Error: Operation timed out after 30009 milliseconds with 0 bytes received

Anyone have suggestion to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer here is likely what you're looking for https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/346236/31838

Increase the request timeout with a `http_request_timeout` filter

```
function custom_http_request_timeout( ) {
    return 90;
}
add_filter( 'http_request_timeout', 'custom_http_request_timeout' );
```